# Dependency Injection in onion architecture for .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, architecture, onion-architecture

I am trying to implement the onion architecture in a .NET Core 3.1 Web API project with EntityFramework as the ORM.

Since I am just learning the onion architecture, I am having a little problem with how to follow it's rules for certain areas. One of them is the dependency injection.

Lets say we have the following rings (Outer to Inner):

- Infrastructure (API, Persistence)
- Application (Services)
- Domain (Models + Domain Services)

From what I understand in the onion architecture, separate concerns in the same layer should not depend on one another. Therefore, in the Infrastructure ring, and more specifically in the API project, I understand how to hookup the DI for my services, since those services (interfaces and implementations) are in the lower rings. However, I also need to setup DI for my DbContext which is defined in the Persistence project of the same ring. Also additional third party tools which will also live in the same ring, also need to be hooked up through the DI.

There are two solutions I see to this:

1. Make the API project depend on the Persistence project (and on additional third party projects). This breaks the onion architecture rules as I understand.
2. Split the Infrastructure ring into two rings where lower half would contain the Web API, Persistence and any additional projects, but upper half would be dedicated DI layer which would setup all the DI. I believe this outer layer is called a composition root.

To just summarize to my question in a different way: In an onion architecture, if you are using DI, the DI looks like it should be in the Infrastructure ring and it looks like the DI needs to reference everything in the Infrastructure ring. Does DI have to be handled as an exception in onion architecture? How to handle this?

Comment: Note that the different services and layers don't have to map to separate projects.  And that project references, per se, do not create the kind dependencies you are trying to avoid.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: For your first point, I agree. However in my mind, if the code/project structure mirrors (or semi mirrors) the architecture, it helps with readability, and for new people jumping on board it helps them to understand where things should go. For your second point, I am a little confused, since if A references B, then people can use anything that resides in B in A. I think what you are saying is that referencing projects does not create direct dependencies? Can you elaborate what you meant?

Comment: It's a fantasy that you can _enforce_ an architecture by any means other than code review.  It may be convenient or sometimes necessary to have direct project references for compilation or deployment, even if your code doesn't directly use types in the referenced project.

Comment: A common example is where your Main project registers the services.  The simplest solution is to have the Main project refer to the types of each service implemetnation.  EG `services.AddScoped<ICustomerRepository, MySQLServerCustomerRepository>();`  and you can't compile that code without a reference to the assembly containing the repository implementation.

Comment: I think you are jumping to extremes :) Of course I know that I wont be able to "enforce" it, but why not logically, based on the architecture, structure the projects? We do add suffixes such as ".Data" or ".Services" right?

Comment: It's fine to use separate projects, but the project structure driven more by the team structure, and deployment concerns.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my understanding:

When compiling, the domain does not depend on anything out of itself. Therefore, for example, the domain would not depend on the persistence project. It would depend on abstractions defined within the domain itself.

Your persistence (for example, concrete repositories) would fulfill the dependencies defined in the domain. In real-world terms that usually means they would implement interfaces defined in the domain.

The composition root then configures the application so that the concrete implementations are matched with the abstractions defined within the domain. That's the DI configuration.

That's the simplest version. You can add more complexity to that if you need it. The only part that wouldn't change is that the domain is self-contained. Here are some other ways that the complexity could grow *if needed*:

- The implementation of dependencies could also be self-contained, like the domain. Yet another project adapts them to the domain interfaces. So your repositories wouldn't directly implement domain interfaces.
- The configuration of domain abstractions - mapping them to their concrete dependencies - could be separated. In other words, your container setup could be separated from the application host. Ideally the application host would remain responsible for reading its configuration or environment values and passing them to that container configuration. That keeps the container configuration from being coupled to details like JSON or .config files. It's easier to test.

But the critical detail is that in any case the domain itself is self-contained. We wouldn't inject an interface defined outside the domain into a domain class. The domain defines its own abstractions, and then classes defined outside of the domain fulfill those abstractions.

---

Your API can depend on the persistence project. Your API is not the domain. Your API startup would depend on the domain and the persistence and configure the DI container to supply classes from the persistence project to fulfill dependencies defined in the domain.

The API is like the opposite of the domain. The domain depends on nothing outside of itself. Other dependencies point inward. The repositories, for example, implement abstractions defined by the domain.

The API on the other hand, ultimately depends on everything. It uses the DI configuration to supply dependencies (like persistence) to the domain, which means it's going to depend on all of them.

---

Here's (in my opinion) the biggest change in thinking:

We have a tendency to write concrete classes for data access, to call external APIs, and do other things that are peripheral to the domain. Then we put interfaces on them. Those interfaces often look like an afterthought. It's like we're just creating interfaces that mirror those classes. If we add something to the class, we add it to the interface.

Then we take those interfaces and start injecting them into our domain. That's where things get messy. Those interfaces have nothing to do with our domain. They're just mirror images of classes that exist outside the domain. It makes the domain harder to test. Interface Segregation is violated. We find ourselves mocking parts of interfaces that have nothing to do with our domain.

All of that goes away if we design our abstractions from the point of view of the domain classes that depend on them. For example, if our domain class needs to retrieve data from a repository, we define a repository that models exactly what that domain class needs - nothing more, nothing less. We don't take some generic all-purpose repository interface and jam it into our domain.

We might still have some generic all-purpose repository. That's okay. But we adapt it to that domain repository interface. The domain doesn't know about it. All it knows about is the abstraction defined in the domain. The domain class depends on small, segregated abstractions it defines for its own purposes. It owns them. That keeps it simple and makes it really easy to test.

Comment: I agree with most of what are you saying. While you are focusing on domain layer, there is also the application layer which also has the same constraints (except it can depend on domain, while domain cannot depend on anything). However, if you think conceptually, why would API need access to persistence details? API are just end points which will use the Application layer services.

Comment: The API would only need access to persistence classes to the extent that the configuration (supplying persistence to the domain) is in the startup of the API. If that configuration is elsewhere (is that the application layer you're referring to?) then the API would only depend on that.

Comment: The API would only need access only to the DTOs. The application services only use DTOs and these DTOs are defined on the application ring. I guess API could access the domain models, but I dont do it that way. Also I dont have two different versions of models, I just have domain models and they are in the domain ring. The persistence project has classes for DbContext and anything other EF configuration tweaks

Comment: The API is going to depend on everything. The domain classes are executing in the context of the API. In order for the API to do anything it has to invoke the domain classes. One way of looking at it: Can the domain work without the API? Yes. You can run unit tests. You don't need an API. Can the API work without the domain? No. Without the domain, what would it do with the DTOs?

Comment: The terminology "has access to" probably doesn't help. (I used it too.) It's probably more helpful to talk in terms of what something depends on. The domain can compile without depending on anything outside of itself. In order to actually execute there must be implementations of its abstractions. When I think of the onion architecture I'm thinking of what is needed to compile the code. The domain can compile without any implementations of its abstractions, but it requires them to actually execute.

Comment: I have posted a solution to my issue. Now I have to test it. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved my situation. I think it is pretty clean although I have to test a lot of more scenarios/use cases before I can safely adopt this solution.

In addition to my API project, I also created a DI project. This DI project is the composition root project. It has dependencies on everything (application, domain, etc) It is the upper part (the outer sub-ring) of the Infrastructure ring. Then, in my API project, I am referencing the DI project and calling an extension method from there to tie up all my contracts to implementations. In addition, I had to add a second web application for something else as part of this same solution and I was able to use the same method, which is good.